# Creature that swims in the solid ground

Tags: creature-design, science-fiction, aliens

I have a moment in my story where the main character comes across a planet with "solid" swamps. Let me explain.

Basically, there are creatures here that can swim through the ground like it was some very thin liquid, however, when any other organism comes in contact with the substance, it's like walking on solid ground. This creature would be relatively large (around the size of a killer Whale) and prey on the other species that find themselves in the middle of these plots of solid alien swampland.

What are the possible organs, adaptations, and behaviors a creature like this would possess, along with what type of substance would exhibit this ability?

Comment: Similar (but not a duplicate!) to https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/84412/what-would-an-efficient-swimming-creature-in-magma-be-like

Comment: Reminds me a bit of "Navy Day," a sci-fi short by Harry Harrison.  Not really an amazing story; I can summarize it in a comment box: the army develops a field generator that makes it possible to cross water as though it were land (with tanks, troops, etc.) and claims this obsoletes the navy.  The navy then develops a field generator to make land navigable as though it were water, e.g. by battleships.

Comment: Can the ground be sand? If so, check out [this guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandworm_(Dune))

Comment: @pipe that's very interesting, however I was thinking of something a little firmer than sand. Maybe gravel or some type of dirt

Comment: Sounds like hortaculture to me...

Comment: @Wildcard your comment makes me think of Supreme Commander 2 - one faction forgoes a navy in favor of hover-tanks, another gives their navy legs (and later, limited use VTOL engines)

Comment: The [Nibelsnarfs](http://monsterhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Nibelsnarf) of Monster Hunter 3U are another example. Though there aren't many physiological details.

Comment: In StarCraft 2, the Zerg's ability to burrow - and move while burrowed in some cases - is explained thusly: `They have billions of tiny muscles that vibrate at a low frequency, effectively loosening soil, crumbling rock, and snapping vegetation.` It is later described as effectively 'swimming' through the ground, though not as fast as through water. Granted, most Zerg are quite a bit smaller than you're describing. Not sure how feasible an explanation this really is, but there's precedent in fiction for it already at the very least.

Comment: This is of course, essentially [Tremors](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100814/)

Comment: What is wrong with a rainworm.

Comment: On earth, we have [sandfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scincus_scincus).

Comment: Be careful to walk arhythmically in the swamps, or you might summon the great Shai Hulud, may his coming cleanse us all.

Comment: In *The Chronicles of Narnia*, living trees "waded" in the earth the same way you'd wade in water.

Comment: It's a great idea, @KingMagmaBlock. It reminds me of the scene in _Illusions_ by R Bach, where the guy swims in the solid ground...

Comment: If you're still looking for other possibilities you might want to take a look as Supercritical Liquids for ideas.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Edit: I've incorporated some of the suggestions from the comments

I'm not sure how possible this would be in real life, but as you've not used science-based or hard science tags I think this should be believable enough.

What you're looking for is a [Non-Newtonian Fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Newtonian_fluid). The most famous of these is probably corn starch in water (or custard, which often amounts to the same thing) which is a liquid but if enough pressure is applied to it it becomes solid and can be walked on, if you do it right. Now that's not quite what you are looking for, you want your unwary prey not to realize they are in a 'swamp' of sorts so needing to walk in a specific way is out of the question.

So here's where we start to play with things. We make the Non-Newtonian Fluid (let's call them NNFs for short) a lot thicker, so that instead of requiring careful high pressure movements to make it solid instead it's solid most of the time but if you move slowly and gently enough through it behaves like a liquid.
Edit: Apparently this is possible even without any handwaving, what we need is called a shear thinning fluid - the faster you try to move it, the easier it is to do so. Thanks to [Agent_L](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/88816/creature-that-swims-in-the-solid-ground/88821?noredirect=1#comment263575_88821) and [Aliden](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/88816/creature-that-swims-in-the-solid-ground/88821?noredirect=1#comment263631_88821) in the comments

According to this [website](http://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/about-this-show/swimming-in-syrup/) it is possible to swim in an NNF, and in fact it's easier the bigger you are. That suits us fine as you want a fairly large creature.

So lets look at the creature itself now. It needs to be making slow and gentle movements to maintain the liquidity of the NNF so it's not likely to be a chasing predator. Ambush seems much more likely and sensible. So we want a creature that waits under the surface for it's prey to walk over head before springing up. As pointed out by [anaximander](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/88816/creature-that-swims-in-the-solid-ground/88821?noredirect=1#comment263560_88821) in the comments springing should work fine, even if it causes the NNF to solidify a large and strong enough creature should have no problem bursting through a thin layer of solid ground.
Waiting for prey to walk over head isn't the best strategy though, you want to lure your prey over. Conveniently your creature also probably needs some kind of snorkel like device to breathe (I'm not sure gills would be effective in an NNF) and we can combine that with a luring mechanism, something that rises up and sits above the ground (in fact maybe it grabs the prey and drags them down, which might be easier than springing up through the NNF).

The first thing that comes to mind is an Angler Fish, one of these beasties:
[image: Angler Fish]

Other options suggested in the comments include;
A [snapping turtle](https://www.natgeocreative.com/comp/05/058/417383.jpg) like creature (suggested by [Dent7777](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/88816/creature-that-swims-in-the-solid-ground/88821?noredirect=1#comment263614_88821)) - In real life snapping turtles already use a lure to hunt. Our creature would be a vastly scaled up version whose head was heavily camouflaged and disguised with a lure that sat inside it's open mouth. The head would sit above ground and wait for prey to enter the mouth before swallowing it.

A creature whose large mouth rises up to envelop it's prey and swallow them whole (as suggested by [Andrew Cheong](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/88816/creature-that-swims-in-the-solid-ground/88821?noredirect=1#comment263734_88821)). I would imagine in this instance the creature would probably be snake like (indeed a Dune style sand worm, as mentioned in other answers, would fit the bill).

Comment: This was awesome to read. Thanks a bunch. I have a fairly good idea about what I'm going to do now

Comment: @KingMagmaBlock No problem, glad it helped. It's probably best to leave the question open for a while though as the brilliant minds here might come up with something better.

Comment: That last leap for the ambush can still be viable even if the fluid solidifies. There are creatures that bury themselves under thin layers of dirt or sand in order to ambush prey. Perhaps this creature has very strong fins, enough to burst out from what is essentially soil at that point, but it can't swim that way *all* the time because it would be incredibly tiring, so it saves it for that sudden strike when prey turns up.

Comment: @anaximander Nice idea. Imagine the very slow way it 'melts' back into the surface after having caught its prey. That makes the animal even more lurid/ominous.

Comment: @anaximander Good point, if it's not buried too deeply then bursting out probably shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: A burrowing ambush predator seems the best bet.

Comment: Non-newtonian fluids also work the other way, eg mayo is solid, but when you hit it hard enough, it flows. A really thick mayo + a really powerful and fast whale = profit!

Comment: @Agent_L  yeah, I did think that was the case but the info I'd found wasn't 100% clear. Thanks for confirming that.

Comment: @JanDoggen I'm thinking of something like a crocodile - it swims to the riverbank slooowly, bursts out to grab a zebra or wildebeest or whatever, finishes it relatively quickly, and then sits and basks for a while to digest. Only, with this, that sitting and basking would cause it to sink slowly back into the ground, which is a terrifyingly cool mental image. It might even restrain its prey, like a constrictor snake, and then use that sinking to suffocate it.

Comment: "...not the best source..." -- *checks link: Mythbusters. ...Can you come up with a better source that makes science understandable (and fun!) for the average Joe?

Comment: @Frostfyre I didn't necessarily mean that, just the site (while professing to be somehow related to the Discovery channel, which it may well be) didn't seem all that reliable. If it is a genuine Mythbusters thing than that is a pretty good source as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: I am thinking your creature might be like a giant alien snapping turtle. Hell, those things look pretty alien as it is! They already have an established practice of lure hunting, so the adaptation is pretty believable. I am picturing their mouths resembling either an overturned tree with a tasty looking mushroom or a large lily pad with a flowering fruit in the middle. This would allow the creature to hunt without having to spring or accelerate quickly. It could move during the nighttime, repositioning itself or rearranging its environs to steer into its gaping maw.

Comment: @adaliabooks There are actually different types of NNFs. The type you described in your answer is what is known as a shear thickening fluid - the faster you try to move it, the harder it is to do so. What Agent_L has described is a shear thinning fluid - the faster you try to move it, the easier it is to do so. Both are viable, but a shear thinning fluid might make a little more sense for an ambush predator because it can then move quickly.

Comment: @Aliden The Wikipedia article I linked does go into the differences but I wasn't sure enough of my interpretation of it to try and name the type that would work. I'll probably edit the answer with some of the extra info provided by the comments.

Comment: Quicksand stands out as a non-newtonian fluid:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksand

It sheer thinning, that is, it is solid except when subjected to force. So it seems solid but collapses when you step on it, and solidifies again when you are waist deep. It is natural, so it could plausibly form a landscape, and could be sufficiently viscous that you could walk on it or even drive vehicles over it but a huge sandworm could still trigger fluidity.

Comment: Great answer. I think snapping out, whether being so close to surface or via thinning liquids, is a little... predictable? Too normal? You said your creature was large, right? What if it didn't even need to move fast, because of its size? _e.g._ You just start feeling a rumbling, then you see all around you something coming out of the sand, but by the time you realize what's going on, you're already standing in the center of the mouth of the beast. Horrifying!

Comment: I'm thinking this creature's mouth actually blends in with the surface...and it's mouth-closure (lips/whatever) can be opened without changing the outer shape of it's skull (imagine if you have your teeth parted but lips closed, then you can just open your lips without moving your jaw). It waits for you to walk on top, and then opens wide!

Comment: Tentacles might be useful to capture prey and would allow the creature to position itself for the snatch fairly easily as long as the ends move slowly. Another possibility is the creature's skin emits a chemical that increases the liquidity of the swamp immediately surrounding the skin, and even that the actual surface is not that dense (2-3 feet) with a more natural liquid below.

Comment: Reminds me of this drawing by Mary Doodles: https://marydoodles.deviantart.com/art/Don-t-trust-the-apple-tree-412817648

Comment: @tgray Yeah, that's pretty much what I'm thinking. Obviously the lure would be dependant on what kind of prey it's hunting, but that's definitely the general idea.

Answer (score 24):

I would suggest a creature that can create enough vibrations around it to make sand behave like liquid.

https://youtu.be/zjgURBIqJ6s?t=2m15s

Then it would be relatively easy for it to move through because the sand will auto vibrate away when pushed against.

Explanation of the mechanics:

> Soil liquefaction describes a phenomenon whereby a saturated or partially saturated soil substantially loses strength and stiffness in response to an applied stress, usually earthquake shaking or other sudden change in stress condition, causing it to behave like a liquid.
>
> The phenomenon is most often observed in saturated, loose (low density or uncompacted), sandy soils. This is because a loose sand has a tendency to compress when a load is applied; dense sands by contrast tend to expand in volume or 'dilate'. If the soil is saturated by water, a condition that often exists when the soil is below the ground water table or sea level, then water fills the gaps between soil grains ('pore spaces'). In response to the soil compressing, this water increases in pressure and attempts to flow out from the soil to zones of low pressure (usually upward towards the ground surface). However, if the loading is rapidly applied and large enough, or is repeated many times (e.g. earthquake shaking, storm wave loading) such that it does not flow out in time before the next cycle of load is applied, the water pressures may build to an extent where they exceed the contact stresses between the grains of soil that keep them in contact with each other. These contacts between grains are the means by which the weight from buildings and overlying soil layers are transferred from the ground surface to layers of soil or rock at greater depths. This loss of soil structure causes it to lose all of its strength (the ability to transfer shear stress) and it may be observed to flow like a liquid (hence 'liquefaction').
>
> A state of 'soil liquefaction' occurs when the effective stress of soil is reduced to essentially zero, which corresponds to a complete loss of shear strength. This may be initiated by either monotonic loading (e.g. single sudden occurrence of a change in stress – examples include an increase in load on an embankment or sudden loss of toe support) or cyclic loading (e.g. repeated change in stress condition – examples include wave loading or earthquake shaking). In both cases a soil in a saturated loose state, and one which may generate significant pore water pressure on a change in load are the most likely to liquefy. This is because a loose soil has the tendency to compress when sheared, generating large excess porewater pressure as load is transferred from the soil skeleton to adjacent pore water during undrained loading. As pore water pressure rises a progressive loss of strength of the soil occurs as effective stress is reduced. It is more likely to occur in sandy or non-plastic silty soils, but may in rare cases occur in gravels and clays (see quick clay).

Source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soil_liquefaction

As to what organs that creature should possess, I'd look at the crocodile, and expand that

https://gizmodo.com/im-amazed-by-what-happens-during-this-alligators-mating-1713932794

Crocodiles produce strong infrasound waves that sends water around them flying away.

> The bellowing cycle of an American alligator. Starting with head and tail lifted in the so-called 'head oblique tail arched' (HOTA) position, and riding high in the water on inflated lungs, the animal sinks into the water as air is expelled through the larynx to create the bellow. Resonance driven by the sound produced makes the water dance from the flanks and then from the dorsum when it submerges towards the end of the event.

https://books.google.nl/books?id=iGYlBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA1925&lpg=PA1925&dq=how+do+crocodiles+produce+infrasound&source=bl&ots=RiHVYBGrTk&sig=_qRV4B_8ltCbkS-53FB3ybdo6qM&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixjZeP6djVAhUEb1AKHciuBTk4ChDoAQgrMAE#v=onepage&q=how%20do%20crocodiles%20produce%20infrasound&f=false

Comment: This option has the benefit that it is science based. Liquefaction is something that actually does happen and can be devastating for objects in the area. The ground does not even need to be sand for this to work; I believe it can also work with loose dirt.

Comment: This could be a great answer if it were expanded into a full explanation of the mechanic.

Comment: better like this @Aaron?

Comment: Indeed. That extra bit about alligators makes it even more science-based. Great answer.

Answer (score 20):

The sandworm from Dune immediately popped into mind as the kind of creature you are looking for. Perhaps you can derive some inspiration from it.

A description of its **physiology** from Wikipedia: Sandworms are animals similar in appearance to colossal terrestrial annelids and in other ways to the lamprey. They are cylindrical worm-like creatures with a fearsome array of crystalline teeth that are used primarily for rasping rocks and sand. During his first close encounter with a sandworm in Dune, Paul Atreides notes, "Its mouth was some eighty meters in diameter ... crystal teeth with the curved shape of crysknives glinting around the rim ... the bellows breath of cinnamon, subtle aldehydes ... acids ..."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandworm_(Dune)

From another question:
https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3620/in-the-dune-universe-how-do-the-sandworms-enlarge-the-desert

[image]

Comment: Do sandworms live only in sands? Does sand count as solid ground?

Comment: Sand can be pretty solid. Sand bags used to build walls for cover from gun fire. But these creatures eat through rock too, hence their teeth. From that same physiology paragraph on wikipedia: Sandworms grow to hundreds of meters in length, with specimens observed over 400 metres (1,300 ft) long and 40 metres (130 ft) in diameter, although Paul becomes a sandrider by summoning a worm that "appeared to be" around half a league (2,778 meters = 9121 ft) or more in length.

Saharan desert average depth 150m:  http://piecubed.co.uk/sand-facts/

Comment: Sandbags.. that's the point! Sand alone won't make a wall.

Comment: @L.Dutch Well, I've walked on sand on numerous occasions without falling through it. While it's true that without the bag, the sand wouldn't keep a wall form, so do dirt and water. Still, the ground and the sea stay still, because there is nowhere to go for the dirt and water that isn't already filled with dirt and water. Sand makes a pretty solid ground because in order to fall through it, you have to move your volume of sand, which has to go somewhere. Water does because it has a fairly low viscosity, sand doesn't.

Comment: Or the creatures from Tremors ...

Comment: I would prefer Rek'sai for a reference. Cricket moles are more efficient as predators

Answer (score 17):

The "swamps" are actually the bodies of massive fungal colonies.  They developed a complex symbiotic relationship with small animals that would forage for food and then could be transported in an organic polymer matrix, sort of like the cytoskeletal transport networks in our own cells.  This progressed over time to allow larger and larger creatures to interact with the network by releasing enzymes and signalling molecules to activate the network and break the polymer.  These signals then swiftly degrade after the animal passes through (thanks to enzymes released by the fungus itself) and the polymer reforms.

I'm imagining it started with a relationship sort of like sea anenomes and clownfish, where the fungus provides protection (you can duck back inside to get away from predators) and the animals provide grooming/foraging services.  The larger creatures are predators that evolved the ability to biochemically 'hack' the interface and therefore gain access to the prey that would try to hide.  The larger animal has become essentially a parasite.

Comment: I like this, it's completely left field which is always interesting.

Comment: There are several really good answers posted, but this one immediately became my favorite halfway through the second sentence. Great idea. A "living ground" that can be moved through could be accomplished a few different ways, so it is easy to adapt this answer too. +2

Comment: I particularly like this idea, especially because it gives you a nice opportunity for your characters to beat the system. Perhaps they find that animals who can enter the swamp tend to eat a particular mushroom that provides the enzymes, and they could douse their suit in mushroom extract to trick the fungus. I'm liking this idea more and more, imaging more of a dense plant-like area, and the plants shrink and recoil when exposed to the enzymes.

Answer (score 8):

It's probably easier to define an environment first and then work on a creature that fits into it. So I'm going to advocate for a [peat bog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bog), it's basically solid but, when healthy, it's so saturated that it can act like a liquid, especially if you add some localised energy in the form of vibration.

So what kind of creature swims through essentially solid peat? An Orca is actually a pretty good shape for this environment but I'd go a little thinner and longer with extended trilateral fins along most of the body, the fins ripple for added speed as well as angling for steering. It's going to use [echolocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_echolocation) same as a dolphin except it's going to be a much more powerful vibration emitted from the whole body, this is going to create a [liquefaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquefaction) pocket around the beast allowing it to swim unimpeded. The liquid bubble around our "Land Whale" also serves another function, where it hits the surface the bog surface is going to go from solid but soggy to something the with the properties of tar sucking down prey. This creature could probably survive as a filter feeder and have gills but I think it's more interesting as an air breathing predator. I also like the idea of them hunting in pods like Orca or Dolphins so you'd see them breaching as a pod the way [cetacea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cetacea) do in Earth's oceans.

Answer (score 7):

You can turn rocks to liquid, if you have enough heat and not afraid of it - melt it.

There was [a project](http://www.pravdareport.com/science/tech/07-05-2003/2734-nuclear-0/) for getting rid of nuclear fuel waste - put a lot of it in a big ball made of tungsten. Then heat from fission would heat it up to 3000K(at some sources number 1200C is mentioned, seems a bit low) which is below melting point of tungsten so it stays solid but way above melting point for most of rocks. Also, tungsten is more dense than most of the rocks, so it would sink and bury nuclear waste in the mantle.

Make this ball alive somehow and make it less dense so that it would not sink and you have it.

Comment: Interesting answer, I would suggest placing documentation into it for more detailed information.

Comment: Um okay except rocks are already solid, proverbially so in fact, this answer makes little sense _and_ has no bearing on the question of a swampy land swimmer.

Answer (score 4):

Another option that comes to mind is that the creature is *incredibly dense*, like neutron star material levels dense. So while such a thing wouldn't be possible in the real world, you might be able to get away with it in sci-fi.

By having your critter be so incredibly dense, things that are solid to us as humans would behave like fluids to this creature. Its body would literally just push dirty and rock aside like it was nothing, because relatively speaking, it is.

Comment: Ooh that's also a great idea. Dang now I have to decide between the two comments which one I like more

Comment: @KingMagmaBlock No worries :)

Comment: @KingMagmaBlock, Making it out of neutron star material would shatter my suspension of disbelief. I suspect that it would shatter the suspension of disbelief of most people with a science background. It would be better to have it be some other unexplained substance/phenomenon. Saying it's made out of neutron star material, or even something that approaches that density, allows people to make assumptions as to how the substance behaves. For instance, that such a quantity would not have enough gravity to maintain that density. That it weights ~1.2x10^19kg, which would be...interesting, etc.

Comment: @Makyen I wasn't planning on making the creature's composition literal Neutron Star material, I more just liked the idea that the creature is dense enough to sink through the material I'm describing. I'm pretty sure if it had the mass of something like that, it would most likely die instantaneously, then cause unknown havoc to its own host planet. Thanks for the feedback, however

Comment: Fishes/Killer Whales are not incredibly dense. You cannot swim if you are incredibly dense, you can just *sink*. Look at how difficult it is to maintain a plane in the air (speed + specifically design wings): that's because it is denser than air.

Comment: This is not a great idea, it's terrible!  If the critter was neutron star dense, then the whole planet whose swamp it was swimming through would end up smeared over the surface of the creature in a thin layer - it would not be pushed aside at all. And swimming creatures are fairly buoyant in the medium they swim through, meaning they are fairly close to having the same mean density as that medium. Otherwise they wouldn't swim, they would walk on the sea bed.

Comment: There is absolutely no relation between density of the observer and state of the matter. Solid remains solid, even if your fish is "more solider". The forcing through rock you're describing requires sheer strength and crush resistance, but the fish overall could be as light as aerogel. There is no point of using the gravity to sink, because it means that the creature still has to have even more muscle power to overcome gravity to swim up. So it might be of neutral buoyancy and save half of the power just as well. Just what regular fish and submarines do. WORST.ANSWER.EVER.

Comment: I agree with @Agent_L.  Anyone with the slightest sense of science and most people who like science fiction will have a sense that a creature based on this answer is "not right".  Even if they can't put into words their scientific objections, such a creature will not feel right.  Can you imagine anything living in a fluid that is that much more dense than the fluid? on the order of 100 trillion times more dense?  Either sinks like a rock, or you'd better add in anti-gravity capabilities and do a heck of a lot of hand-waving.

Comment: Just to exapnd on Draco18s answer (since I don't have enough rep to comment): there is already a scifi story with this scenario. On one crazy planet that orbits like number 8 around and between two suns, there are "birds" with much higher density than the ground, so they "fly" through the ground, occasionally ruining foundations of buildings so buildings would collapse. They never went out of solid ground because air and atmosphere has too low density for them. I see people protest about the neotron star density and I agree. In this story it was never applied that "birds" had even close to tha

Comment: @AgapwIesu and Agent_L: the question is not tagged `science-based`, but rather `science-fiction`. Science fiction which is not "hard-sci-fi" often does have this level of hand-wavium all over the place. In fact, my wife gets annoyed when I talk too much about the technical realism of sci-fi movies we watch. +1 to this answer because it would work for 95% or more of its viewers/readers.

Comment: @Aaron - but one of the things we do on this board is point out when ideas are so removed from science that people will not swallow it even as a science-fiction story. I don't know what you are talking about with "hard-sci-fi". There is no such tag. The running practice I've observed here is that even if a question is not tagged with a science tag, does not mean that you won't get dinged for answers from la-la land.  When OP asks "what kind of substance...", the clear implication is that the answer will make some sense. A substance 100 trillion times more dense that its surroundings does not.

Comment: @AgapwIesu I think the issue is one of severity. Your threshold for realism is different. Evident when you (rightly) suggest "when ideas are so removed from science that people will not swallow it". More than half your sci-fi movie viewers would accept this answer, and many of them would not know enough to understand how implausible it is. I'd roll my eyes, think "that's not how it works," then enjoy the movie. Most others don't even know how a neutron star is different. I enjoyed the book Starquake, by Robert Forward, though it did not back up neutron-star-creatures with reasonable science.

Comment: @AgapwIesu I suppose my only real disagreement with you is that I give people more credit for "plausible deniability tolerance" than you but less for their intelligence; I think you give people too much credit. I talk to many about science, and I used to be a college teacher; I suggest most, even sci-fi junkies, are dumber than you think. Even many nerds don't know the difference between star system/galaxy/universe or molecule/atom. WB.SE is the exception because of its nature. Even more don't understand what a nuclear reaction is, much less difference between fusion/fission. I could go on.

Answer (score 3):

In League of Legends there's a champion called Rek'sai. She's a voidborn (an alien from a different realm) and can 'swin' in the ground. She makes the ground vibrate enough to move freely through solid terrain but she also creates portals to travel faster. She's more like a cricket mole but she moves like a shark in the ground.

She's a feared monster in Shurima's desert who can eat expeditions like nothing:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcB-FreSnG8

[image]

She's massive, enough to eat camels with one bite

About the organs:

- The creatures should lack of eyes. Eyes would be a huge disadvantage when you're swimming through solid terrains
- Have an exceptionall smell/hearing
- Almost grills **OR** a blowhole to breath outside, this means they would have massive lungs.
- They must emite constant sound waves (like a purr to disperse the solid materials and swim freely)
- They mostly feel vibrations rather than sounds, since they're underground

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat different approach: make creates that [“glitch”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glitch) through the solid ground. They don’t swim, per se; rather, they propel themselves forward by jerkily disappearing and  reappearing (displacing whatever solid was in their place).

A (very hand-wavy) basis in solid science would be [quantum tunnelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tunnelling): you creatures have evolved a way of generating a coherent quantum field to be able to appear as a [macroscopic quantum object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macroscopic_quantum_phenomena), and to control the probability and direction of tunnelling their whole mass through the surrounding solid.

(Even more hand-wavy would be to rely on the creatures creating localised, temporary wormholes or some other form of teleportation.)

Answer (score 1):

If you ever saw a [mole dig himself into soft ground,](https://youtu.be/XCMQbE0BHyw) swimming is not that far away.

Answer (score 1):

This question instantly reminded me of [Hugh Howey's Halfway Home](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8428985-half-way-home).  In the story, there are tunnel boring wormlike creatures who (if my memory serves me correctly) have an ability to absorb the materials they come into contact with - and then defectate them out the back end turning it into piles of diamonds/gold or something in the process!

Kind of questionable science, but potentially acheivable if the creature possesed some attributes of molecular nanotechnology (the [Gray Goo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_goo) springs to mind here!)

Answer (score 0):

What about something like a giant, but thin amoeba? It would push it's 'membrane' forward in a sharp point, then flow into it from behind, forcing the membrane outward. If it were moving through sand or loose soil, it may leave a trail visible from the surface, but if it were more of a liquidy material it should flow around and fill in the gap behind.

Not sure how fast it would move, but it's your world...